# How do I take a list and remove it from a file?

Tags: command-line, shell, grep, text-processing

I have a long list of domain names that I need to remove from /etc/remotedomains. They're probably not in any particular order in the file. Each domain is on one line.

How could I iterate through the list and find that line in remote domains and remove it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
grep -Fxf list -v /etc/remotedomains > remotedomains.new
mv remotedomains.new /etc/remotedomains
```

The `-v` tells grep to only output lines that don't match the pattern.

The `-f list` tells grep to read the patterns from the file `list`.

The `-F` tells grep to interpret the patterns as plain strings, not regular expressions (so you won't run into trouble with regex meta-characters).

The `-x` tells grep to match the whole line, e.g. if there's a pattern `foo` that should only remove the line `foo`, not the line `foobar` or `barfoo`.

Comment: note: always remember to backup `/etc/localdomains` and `/etc/remotedomains` before doing stuff like this.

Comment: `-F` is for fixed string matching (“exact matches”), but it does **not** force the pattern to match the whole line. [POSIX specifies the `-x` flag](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) to limit matches to instances where a pattern matches the whole line.

Comment: @Chris: Bah, good catch.

Answer (score 1):

Use comm!

```bash
comm -23 /etc/remotedomains remove
```

From the man page:

> Compare sorted files FILE1 and FILE2 line by line.
>
> With no options, produce three-column output.  Column one contains lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to FILE2, and column three contains lines common to both files.

Options -1, -2 and -3 disable respective columns.

It does however require that files be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

`sed -r -i -e '/^(domain1|domain2|domain3|...|domainN)$/d' domainlist.txt`

If your list of domains to delete is in a file then:

`sed -r -i -e '/^'"$(xargs <removelist.txt|sed -e 's/ /|/g)"')$/d' domainlist.txt`

Notes:

1. Use -i.bak to have sed make a backup of domainlist.txt
2. If removelist.txt has **many** thousands of entries, it could overflow the maximum command line length.  This is not a very likely scenario but something you should be aware of.

On further reflection, that risk can be eliminated with:

```sh
for RE in $(xargs <removelist.txt|sed -e 's/ /|/g') ; \
  do sed -r -i -e '/^('"$RE"')$/d' domainlist.txt ; \
done
```